# From Fourier series to DFT

Tags: fourier-series, fast-fourier-transform

A complex function $f(x)$ that is periodic on $[0,2L]$ can be represented as  infinite sum of a complex, orthonormal exponential functions that represent the frequencies that reside in $f$.

$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}  c_k e^{\frac{i\pi kx}{L}} $$

Where $c_k$  are the coefficients for the frequencies and are given by

$$ c_k = \frac{1}{2L}  \int_{0}^{2L} f(x) e^{\frac{-i\pi kx}{L}} dx   $$

This is the Fourier series definition. However when moving to DFT we have

$$
X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] \cdot e^{-j \cdot 2\pi \cdot k \cdot n / N}
$$

$$x[n] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] \cdot e^{j \cdot 2\pi \cdot k \cdot n / N}$$

In the last formula, I'm not sure how the sum from $k=0 $ to $k=N-1$
matches  $ f(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}  c_k e^{\frac{i\pi kx}{L}}$  because it does not include negative k's

Comment: First of all, $n$ is not a constant, $N$ is. And $N/2$ might not even be an integer, so and thus the sum from $-N/2$ to $N/2-1$ might not even be defined.

Comment: Fixed the problem

Comment: You need to think of indices as modulo $N$. In that sense, $N-1$ is the same as $-1$, $N-2$ is the same as $-2$ etc... So that's how it "matches" negative frequencies.

Comment: In which formula you can replace k=N-1 with k=-1 and k=N-2 with k=-2 ?

Comment: $x[n]$ and $X[n]$ have period of length $N,$ so any sum of $N$ consecutive values works, but we choose $0$ to $N-1$ because it is the easiest set of $N$ consecutive values.

Comment: Fourier series is for continuous function while DFT is for discrete signal, why do you expect a full coincidence?

Comment: Because integral is just a sum in the discrete  case and I'm sure the formula for the discrete case was derived from Fourier series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DFT operates on a finite set of discrete samples, as a result it produces a corresponding set of discrete frequency components. Now, to understand why the DFT does not **explicitly** handle negative frequencies, let's focus on the exponential term in the DFT. For a given index $k$, the term $\mathrm{e}^{-i \frac{2\pi}{N} kn}$ represents a complex sinusoidal function with a frequency of $\frac{k}{N}$ cycles per sample. We can see this from Euler's formula, where the general form of a complex exponential function is given by:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{e}^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta).
\end{equation}
In the context above, we have $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{N}kn$. Substituting this into Euler's formula, we get
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{e}^{-i \frac{2\pi}{N} kn} = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{N}kn\right) - i \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{N}kn\right).
\end{equation}
This expression represents a complex sinusoidal function with a frequency of $\frac{k}{N}$. Consequently, the entire exponential term $\mathrm{e}^{-i \frac{2\pi}{N} kn}$ can be seen as a combination of cosine and sine functions with this frequency.

Now, if we multiply this term by the input sequence $x[n]$ and sum over all values of $n$, we essentially evaluate how much of this sinusoidal component is present in the signal at the frequency $\frac{k}{N}$. Hence, the exponential term in the DFT represents a complex sinusoidal function whose frequency is determined by the index $k$ and the length of the sequence $N$, increasing $k$ means increasing the frequency.

In the context of DFT, the frequency index $k$ ranges from 0 to $N-1$. Since the DFT assumes that the signal is periodic with a period of $N$, it only considers frequencies that are multiples of the fundamental frequency $\frac{1}{N}$. As a result, there is **no explicit** representation of negative frequencies in the DFT. However, the DFT implicitly handles negative frequencies due to its periodic nature. The positive frequencies are repeated periodically, and any negative frequency components can be interpreted as a wrapping or folding of the positive frequencies, as @Stefan Lafon already pointed out.

In practical terms, when you analyze the DFT output, the frequency components at indices $k$ and $N-k$ are often considered to be symmetric in magnitude but differ in phase. This symmetry reflects the periodic nature of the DFT and the **implicit** handling of both positive and negative frequencies within the periodic framework.